# For $f(x) = a x^2 + bx + c$, find $ d +e(i) $ that will generate a real value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

[image]

This is the challenge question, I don't understand how because $i$ must be squared in order for it to be $-1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint $1$:

you just have to make the sum of the terms with $i$ involved $0$, the only condition will be $d=-\frac{b}{2a}$ when $e \neq 0 $ otherwise it always happens. (assuming $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{R}$)

Hint $2$ :

$$f(d+ei) = a(d+ei)^2+b(d+ei)+c = ad^2-ae^2+2daei +bd+bei+c = $$
$$ad^2-ae^2+bd+c +(2dae+be)i$$

Comment: I still don't quite understand yet. Could you give me more hints?

Comment: I updated  right now:), have you found a way to link the hints? anyway I suggest you to be more clear with your problem and the description on where you are stuck because otherwise people can be not willing to help you , helping someone which is committing is much more useful

Comment: @Dan Nguyen Plug in $d = -b/2$ into the final equation and simplify it. What happens?

Comment: @Tortar ? typo alert : hint 2 : line 1 : s/b ...+ 2adei + ...

Comment: oh right, I made it quickly and I forgot something :P